# Probability of Hearts given Hearts Was Chosen

Tags: probability

Suppose we had a normal 52 count deck of cards. If two cards are randomly picked, what is the probability that both are Hearts given at least one Heart was chosen.

I think the answer would be $ \frac{12}{51}$ because there are twelve Hearts left after one is chosen with 51 total cards, but I might be approaching this problem the wrong way. Any idea on how I should think about it, or what I did wrong?

Comment: seems right to me

Comment: You found the probability that the second card selected is a heart given that the first card selected is a heart.

Comment: Probability first one is a heart: $\frac{13}{52}$, Probability second one is a heart assuming first one chosen was a heart: $\frac{12}{52}$. Probability that both occur is the product of the previous two fractions.

Comment: This is a variation on the popular question: A couple has two children.  What is the probability that both are sons given that one of two is a son $\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)$ versus the probability that both are sons given that the first is a son $\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)$ .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note:
$$P(H\cap H)=\frac{13}{52}\cdot \frac{12}{51}.$$
$$P(H'\cap H')=\frac{39}{52}\cdot \frac{38}{51}.$$
$$\frac{P(H\cap H)}{1-P(H'\cap H')}=\frac{2}{15}.$$

Answer (score 4):

There are 3 possibilities to consider:

1. No hearts chosen
2. One heart chosen
3. Two hearts chosen

The chance of #1 is $\frac{39\cdot 38}{52\cdot 51}$

The chance of #2 is $\frac{2\cdot 39\cdot 13}{52\cdot 51}$

The chance of #3 is $\frac{13\cdot 12}{52\cdot 51}$

You can confirm that the probabilities of #1, #2, and #3 add to 1.

#2 and #3 represent cases that at least one heart was chosen. Therefore chance of two hearts chosen given that at least one was chosen are:

$\frac{13\cdot 12}{2\cdot 39\cdot 13+13\cdot 12} = \frac2{15} \approx 13.3\%$